# TypeFace is not working when using multiple times

Tags: android

My design:

[image]

Look at my android code below:

```
final ArrayList<String> arrayFont = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayFont.add("Arial");
    arrayFont.add("Segoeui");
    arrayFont.add("Tahoma");
    arrayFont.add("Times New Roman");
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,arrayFont);
    sp.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(position == 0){
                Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/arial.ttf");
                txtkq.setTypeface(type);
            }
            if(position == 1){
                Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/segoeui.ttf");
                txtkq.setTypeface(type);
            }
            if(position == 2){
                Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/tahoma.ttf");
                txtkq.setTypeface(type);
            }
            if(position == 3){
                Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/times.ttf");
                txtkq.setTypeface(type);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

 protected void Checked(View v){
    if(cb_Bold.isChecked() && cb_Italic.isChecked() == false) {
        Typeface bold_Typeface = Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD);
        txtkq.setTypeface(bold_Typeface);
    }else
    if(cb_Italic.isChecked() && cb_Bold.isChecked() == false){
        Typeface Italic_Typeface = Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.ITALIC);
        txtkq.setTypeface(Italic_Typeface);
    } else
    if(cb_Bold.isChecked() && cb_Italic.isChecked()){
        Typeface bold_Italic_Typeface = Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
        txtkq.setTypeface(bold_Italic_Typeface);
    }else
    if(cb_Bold.isChecked() == false && cb_Italic.isChecked() == false){
        Typeface bold_Italic_Typeface = Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.NORMAL);
        txtkq.setTypeface(bold_Italic_Typeface);
    }
}
```

When i click change font, it's work, but then i click change font Style to **Bold** or *Italic* , it's back to default Font :( Change Font with spinner in onCreate and Change Font Style with checkbox outside of onCreate. Checked is onClick event of Checkbox in XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because every type you are selecting font OR font famlily, you are adding new type face to the view. Try below code

```
textview.setTypeface(textview.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
```

When you are changing text style also get the current type of the textview and pass with new type face. Hope that answers the question.

Comment: But i can't use typeface NORMAL, can you help me?

Comment: what is the problem you are facing in setting typeface normal?

Comment: txtkq.setTypeface(txtkq.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);

Answer (score 0):

Please try this..

```
protected void Checked(View v){
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)v;
        if(checkBox.isChecked()) {
            Typeface bold_Typeface = Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD);
            editText.setTypeface(bold_Typeface);
        } else {
            Typeface bold_Italic_Typeface = Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.NORMAL);
        editText.setTypeface(bold_Italic_Typeface);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See the definition for the setTypeface method. If you dont pass a typeface (font), it applies the default one to it. Style is basically the textStyle you want like bold, italic. So while setting your style you should also pass your typeface font as suggested above.

```
public void setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style) {
        if (style > 0) {
            if (tf == null) {
                tf = Typeface.defaultFromStyle(style);
            } else {
                tf = Typeface.create(tf, style);
            }
}
```

So you should try the code :

```
Typeface ft=textview.getTypeface();
textview.setTypeface(ft, Typeface.BOLD);
```

Comment: i don't understand what u're saying :(

Comment: The 1st piece of code is the setTypeface method in the android SDK. Please refer it in android studio. This method has two parameters you see, one Typeface that specifies the font type and other int that defines the style. When you are using setTypeface method in your code, you are only passing an int i.e. style and in that case android automatically set by default Typeface (See my first piece of code). So just replace it with 2nd piece of code. What you are not getting in this?